# Azure cloud service vs2012 web role publishing breaks Chrome browser caching

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure

When I publish Web Roles to Azure Cloud services using vs2012 to publish an Azure Tools 2.2 project the files packaged and sent to the instance servers are marked as last modified 1 hour in the future. Therefore Chrome does not provide browser caching of the files for 1 hour!

I know that the Azure servers are all UTC time based, and that they have no daylight saving time enabled, whereas my development PC is set for Day light saving time enabled one hour ahead.

What I can't find (don't even know where to start looking) is how to set / change / fix this.

At the moment I am changing my Development PC time before publishing - what do the PST developers do? or am I the only one with this issue.

Comment: Gave up the packaging element sometime ago as it was ridiciously flaky - the direct Publish from VS works a treat.  Regarding Chrome caching, you can disable this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development